# Drive undetectable after deleting all of its partitions

Tags: hard-drive

I deleted all the partitions of two of my three 1TB drives and now I can no longer access them in any form or way anymore. The disk manager of Windows does not show them, they do show up in devices on Windows and also in the BIOS.

I have tried numerous programs to try and get them back, but I just can't seem to be able to do it. Any ideas as to how I can regain access to my disks?

Comment: Diskpart only detects the main drive and the plugged in USB, forgot to mention, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Get a Linux live CD - any kind should do.
2. Boot that CD (or USB flash drive possibly)
3. Run `gparted`, `gnome-disks` (=disks) or any other partitioning tool on that live CD.
4. Remove all partition traces first, then create at least one new. Remember that Linux tools know a lot more partition types than Windows, so be conservative.

Comment: I was thinking about doing this as well, but now that someone gave that as an idea, I might even try it.

Comment: Alright, I have tried doing this and it worked like a charm! Linux easily allowed me to edit all partitions by just opening a terminal using ctrl+alt+t and running gparted. Linux even has an option to format them to NTFS!